# Change screen resolution shortcut with correct aspect ratio (letterboxing)

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to create a shortcut or command to change my screen from its native resolution to `1280 x 720` (720p).

Of course the image should not be stretched to my 5:4 screen. It should make a centered letterboxed 720p image.

Intel HD Graphics Control Panel has a setting to keep scaling as Centered, but it fails to work when setting a new resolution with a command. Intel have failed to include command-line options for switching profiles in their app, which should be illegal, along with installers without a silent switch.

I've tried [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) `setdisplay`, [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) `DllCall(ChangeDisplaySettingsA)` and [a Powershell script](https://web.archive.org/web/20160821202522/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/07/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-change-my-desktop-monitor-resolution-via-windows-powershell/) using `User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings`. They all override the scaling setting.

It's unclear whether scaling is something that can be dictated from the `User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings` API or not.

Solution should work on Windows 7 and up.

**EDIT** Getting closer, the [MSDN documentation of the DEVMODE structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) describes what I want as `dm.dmDisplayFixedOutput = DMDFO_CENTER;`

Comment: Potentially useful:
-- [SOLVED] How To Change Resolution of Both Monitors At Once? - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=19467
-- autohotkey - How do I click on the Hyper link text Automatically when window active using auto hot key scripting / Batch File - Stack Overflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845318/how-do-i-click-on-the-hyper-link-text-automatically-when-window-active-using-aut/42032149#42032149
-- Retrieving screen info may help confirm if setting screen info will work.
-- Exercise caution if using functions. Good luck.

Comment: @vafylec Yeah I've seen both threads (and commented in the first) but I couldn't figure it out. If someone happens to know off-hand why DMDFO_CENTER doesn't work here, that's great, otherwise I can't spend much time on it because third-party software like DisplayChanger by 12noon already does solve the problem.